# Prove that the measure $A\mapsto\int_Aq(x,y)\mu({\rm d}y)$ is $\sigma$-finite

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space
- $q:E\times E\to[0,\infty]$ be $\mathcal E\otimes\mathcal E$-measurable and $$\kappa(x,A):=\int_Aq(x,y)\mu({\rm d}y)\;\;\;\text{for }(x,A)\in E\times\mathcal A$$

I want to show that $\kappa$ is a $\sigma$-finite transition kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$, i.e.

1. $\kappa(\;\cdot\;,A)$ is $\mathcal E$-measurable, for all $A\in\mathcal E$
2. $\kappa(x,\;\cdot\;)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure, for all $x\in E$

By *Fubini's theorem*, 1. is easily checked. Moreover, we obtain for all $x\in E$ that $\kappa(x,\;\cdot\;)$ is a measure by the *monotone convergence theorem*.

> How do we prove that these measures are $\sigma$-finite?

If that's not possible with the given assumptions, please feel free to strengthen them.

Answer (score 1):

This is false as stated. For example take $q \equiv \infty$.

The statement becomes true if we assume that $q(x, \cdot)<\infty$, $\mu$-a.e. for all (fixed) $x \in E$.

Let's prove this. From now on fix some $x \in E$.

Since $E$ is $\sigma$-finite, we can write $E= \bigcup_m E_m$ with $\mu(E_m)<\infty$ for all $m$. Since we know that $q(x, \cdot)< \infty$ a.s., we can define $A_n = \{y \in E: q(x,y)< n\}$, so that the complement of $\bigcup_n A_n$ has $\mu$-measure zero. Next we note that for $m,n \in \Bbb N$ we have that $$\kappa(x, A_n \cap E_m) = \int_{A_n \cap E_m} q(x,y) \mu(dy) \leq \int_{A_n \cap E_m} n \; \mu(dy) \leq n \cdot \mu(E_m) < \infty$$

Moreover, we have that $E = \bigcup_{m,n \in \Bbb N} A_n \cap E_m$, up to a set of $\mu$-measure zero (which also has $\kappa(x,\cdot)$-measure zero). So, we have written $E$ as a countable union of sets of finite $\kappa(x, \cdot)$-measure, as desired.